# Checking generic type argument in array of mixed generics

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an interface ActionTupel

```
export interface ActionTupel<T extends ID> {
  id: T;
  // based on a given ID it returns a list of rest-params
  // ( ID.test [string,number], ID.print [])
  params: ExecutionParams<T>;
}

export type ExecutionParams<T extends ID> = 
  T extends ID.test ? [string,number] :
  T extends ID.print ? [] : [];
```

and a function to use it

```
public executeActions<C extends ID>(...actions: ActionTupel<C>[]): Result<Last<C>>
```

Now I have a question related to these functions:

**Question**

```
executeActions(
  {
    id: ID.test,
    params: ['test', 1],
  },
  {
    id: ID.print,
    params: ["12", 1],
  })
```

if I try to execute this function with two IDs, it won't throw an error for `ID.print` because the array definition is now `<ID.print | ID.test>`. How can I achieve to throw an error here? params for `ID.print` should be an empty array like []

Added minimal typescript code here without any external libs:

```js
class TestAction implements Action<ID.test, string> {
  readonly type = '[Action] Test';

  execute(foo: string, bar: number): string {
    return 'hello test service';
  }
}

class PrintAction implements Action<ID.print, Date> {
  readonly type = '[Action] Test';

  execute(): Date {
    return new Date();
  }
}

interface ActionTupel<T extends ID> {
  id: T;
  params: ExecutionParams<T>;
}

type ExecuteResult<T extends ID> = ReturnType<ActionClass<T>['execute']>;

/**
 * don't know which aproach is best to handle selecting last of array
 */
type LengthOfTuple<T extends any[]> = T extends { length: infer L }
  ? L
  : never;
type DropFirstInTuple<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => any) extends (
  arg: any,
  ...rest: infer U
) => any
  ? U
  : T;
type LastInTuple<T extends any[]> = T[LengthOfTuple<
  DropFirstInTuple<T>
>];
type Last<T extends []> = T extends [...unknown[], infer R] ? R : never;
/**
 * end
 */

enum ID {
  print = 'print',
  test = 'test',
}

type ActionClass<T extends ID> = T extends ID.print
  ? PrintAction
  : T extends ID.test
  ? TestAction
  : never;

type ExecutionParams<T extends ID> = Parameters<
  ActionClass<T>['execute']
>;

type FunctionType<T extends ID> = ReturnType<ActionClass<T>['execute']>;

interface ActionSet<T extends ID> {
  loadService: () => ActionClass<T>
}

const ACTIONS = new Map<ID, ActionSet<ID>>()
  .set(ID.print, {
    loadService: () => new PrintAction(),
  })
  .set(ID.test, {
    loadService: () => new TestAction(),
  });

 interface Action<C extends ID, T> {
  readonly type: string;
  // describes the chainable function of each action
  execute: (...params: ExecutionParams<C>) => T;
}

 const getAction = <T extends ID>(id: T): ActionSet<T> => {
  if (!ACTIONS.has(id)) {
    return null;
  }

  return ACTIONS.get(id);
};

 class ActionService {
  /**
   * whether the id is known by the service or not
   * @param {ID} id unique id of the action
   * @returns boolean
   */
  public hasValidAction<T extends ID>(id: T): boolean {
    return getAction(id) ? true : false;
  }

  public async executeActions<C extends ID>(
    ...actions: ActionTupel<C>[]
  ): Promise<ExecuteResult<LastInTuple<C[]>>> {
    const items = actions.map((a) => this.executeAction(a.id, ...a.params));
    const r = await Promise.all(items);
    return r[1];
  }

  /**
   * executes a single action by checking for necessary services
   * @param {ID} id unique id of the action
   * @returns Observable<T>
   */
  public async executeAction<T extends ID>(
    id: T,
    ...args: ExecutionParams<T>
  ): Promise<ExecuteResult<T>> {
    const s = await this.getService(id);
    console.log(s.type);
    const r = s.execute.apply(this, args) as FunctionType<T>;
    return r;
  }

  /**
   * retreives service based on passed action id
   * @param {ID} id unique action id
   * @returns Promise<ActionClass<T>>
   */
  private async getService<T extends ID>(id: T): Promise<ActionClass<T>> {
    const actionSet = getAction(id);
    if (!actionSet) {
      return null;
    }

    const s = await actionSet.loadService();
    return s;
  }
}

const service = new ActionService();

// fine
const printR = service.executeAction(ID.print);

// fine
const testR = service.executeAction(ID.test, 'hallo', 1);

// incomplete
const finalR = service.executeActions(
  {
    id: ID.test,
    params: ['test', 1],
  },
  {
    id: ID.print,
    params: ['test', 1], // needs an assertion to be empty
  }
);
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now `ID` is not defined so I immediately see errors when I start trying to look at this code.  If you do decide to [edit] the code to do this and want to ask me to take another look, mention @jcalz in a comment.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbecsz?file=src/app/app.component.ts
@jcalz

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to ask for a *plain text* and *self-contained* [mre] that demonstrates the issue *when pasted* into any TS-enabled IDE.  An external link is great, but all the code necessary for the example should be in the text of the question itself.

Comment: Please read [ask], where it notes, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so— **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Comment: Now that I'm looking at the code, I see that you've got two separate questions about it.  [Please choose just one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).  If you want to ask both you should make two separate posts.

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2zPjw) is how I'd handle Q1.  If you want to ask about Q1, please [edit] your question to only ask that, along with a [mre] including all the necessary code (like the `ID` definition) and no unnecessary code (like the return type of `executeActions`), and I'd be happy to write up an answer.  Mention @jcalz to notify me about what you'd like to do here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a minimal code to the post and deleted the second question. @jcalz

Comment: So do you want me to post an answer with [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2zPjw)?  Does that work for you?  (Please note that your example doesn't seem to be *minimal* since there's a bunch of code there unrelated to the question you're asking.  You probably don't need anything more than [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NB5ynw) in the question.)

Comment: The question name should probably also be updated. Something like "Checking generic type argument in array of mixed generics".
BTW I already posted an answer, similar, but a bit different. I think you should post yours too @jcalz

Comment: @jcalz
Yes, you solved it with this approach, so pls post an answer for everyone. Maybe you could explain a little detail about this approach. Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw, the problem with this:

```
declare function executeActions<C extends ID>(...actions: ActionTuple<C>[]): any;
```

is that `C` is inferred as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the values passed in for `id`, and therefore `params` is also allowed to be a union of the corresponding parameters.  And so it will accept things you don't want to be accepted:

```
executeActions(
  { id: ID.test, params: ['test', 1] },
  { id: ID.print, params: ["12", 1] }  // no error
); // C inferred as ID
```

---

A potential fix is to make `executeActions()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of values passed in for `id`.  That is, if the first argument to `executeActions()` has an `id` of `ID.test` and the second has an `id` of `ID.print`, then we want the type argument to be `[ID.test, ID.print]`.

It could look like this:

```
declare function executeActions<C extends ID[]>(
  ...actions: { [I in keyof C]: ActionTuple<C[I]> }
): any;
```

Here, the `actions` [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) is of a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over `C`, the tuple of `id` properties.  Each element of `C` at index `I` (also known as `C[I]`) is mapped an element of type `ActionTuple<C[I]>`.  So if `C` is `[ID.test, ID.print]`, then `actions` is of type `[ActionTuple<ID.test>, ActionTuple<ID.print>]`.

Let's test it out:

```
executeActions( // C inferred as [ID.test, ID.print]
  { id: ID.test, params: ['test', 1] },
  { id: ID.print, params: ["12", 1] } // error!
  // -----------> ~~~~~~
  // Type '[string, number]' is not assignable to type '[]'
);
```

Looks good.  The type checker is able to infer `C` as `[ID.test, ID.print]` from the arguments passed in for `executeActions()`, and then the second argument is seen to be in error because `params` for `ActionTuple<ID.print>` must be of tpe `[]`, not `[string, number]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAkgIlA3gKClADgJwJYgC5QC8UA5FrniQDSpR7ADOBxJ9T1yAvsshcJgDMAhgGNgUAIIi82APYgAKmHQAbYAB4FUYAA96IACYNYcAHxJa2AwC4oCgNy0A9E6gAjIQ2AGo8qEKgAc2wAN1ATKGwCTGA8MEwQYwCVbCZfASgYpgBadCFMIQgGZ1cAChMAOjYCAG0mHBBAqnAIN34AXSpK8nwoGvaASlo8gqLbAFEdYBEwGXkABXzChk1TR25kPABPdHFJ6dm5EEXRla1dfSMTc0Jac71QK-gqxgIAfj763CaoFrbMdpQax3bQPQzGZ49d59QG2fqOZBOABUUERrhgJB8YC8dAAFqlIol6EIDF03LM8UJKMZZBTZBkGCJZLsoLj+MBgdsWfsZnNjksiuoANKgy4QsxECxoGrPartOFfRpdP4dWgyuAVKHymE0Tg1IXtZBIpw8ECFRh5MRQABCJIstAM0xU+XEAjAIGkR1BB3oUj5KwAwqLHuLTKUKhHRP7bH6jkpVBoA6Z+gNbEIQFtHGhdD7gLH5AxSrQ0IhIjZKtUuiNlnDWK9qFAAIyAzg0NAlsu2SENPBVgUMOEAIkbACZB11m1BuGgBvYoC4oEHcAJ+DEfJ4TDwNmaIBbROIAOKyWQ+FAOp0uqBuj18728vOegvqIMXEMmfph4tQCMVKNHAdIH0MCElAADWwBbPSi7avmijKGoz4yu05jTlAqb+BmCLZlM96wYW86uEuIArpga7+MY6ovEwXTdhQhrtoBVhdhqlYYP2tbVA2k6tl+pZMd0PZ9qcQ6juOTYtgR2ikbImAAIRfgu2RKcpKnZOYAB+mlaQprgKDs4gkHUeAND8KoAiQkTGCAsgEJ4DDYIEZpuGodCyHQ+mkP0JC0LOW5AA)

Comment: I like your "out of scope" suggestion with index access on `ExecutionParams`. I think it's worth mentioning here on top of the playground link

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming:

```
enum ID {
  test,
  print
}
```

#### 1

I think what's happening is that TS is allowing `C` to be a different value that `test` or `print`.
Being more specific works for me:

```
executeActions(...actions: (ActionTupel<ID.test> | ActionTupel<ID.print>)[])
```

or alternatively:

```
type StricterActionTuple = ActionTupel<ID.test> | ActionTupel<ID.print>;
executeActions(...actions: StricterActionTuple<ID.test>[]);
```

---

Answer to old second question:

#### 2

```
type Last<Ar extends []> = Ar extends [ ...unknown[], infer U] ? U : never;
```

Putting it together:

```
type Last<Ar extends []> = Ar extends [ ...unknown[], infer U] ? U : never;
type StricterActionTuple = ActionTupel<ID.test> | ActionTupel<ID.print>;
declare function executeActions<C extends StricterActionTuple[]>(...actions: C): Last<C>;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer 2, but for the first question its not possible with StricterActionTupel as there are more than a hundret entries in that enum.

Comment: @Draftsman yikes, that's a lot of cases. jcalz 's solution would be easier to read for this. Particularly the commented bit with with "I'd use this instead, but that's out of scope".
But depending on your full code, it might be cleaner to refactor into [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)